# How to remain the selected value in multiple select after submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

Halloo Guys!, I have a multiple select input, but after i click submit button i want to remain the value as is in the multiple select. How? It is possible?
Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide a small version of your code to reproduce the behaviour?

Comment: So use ajax , it will remain as you selected and submitted

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of doing that with localStorage:

```js
if(localStorage['multiple']){        
    $.each(localStorage['multiple'].split(","), function(i,e){
        $("select option[value='" + e + "']").prop("selected", true);
    });
}

$('form').submit(function(event) {
    localStorage['multiple'] = $('select').val();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <select multiple>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
  </select>
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to FOCUS and SELECT input value after submit event. The first one is easy, just add "autofocus" as a property to your input element:

```
<input class="inputAreas" name="input1" id="mainInput" autofocus>
```

The second is also easy. On your server script, you'll need to export submitted value as a dynamic data to your render page. Then you can set it a value in your input element.

1.Node.js server script:

```
const wordx = req.body.input1;
```

2.on your new html/ejs page(attention: this should a new html/ejs page):

```
<input class="inputAreas" name="input1" id="mainInput" value=<%= wordx %> autofocus>
```

3. then again on the same page, open a script area, and

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      document.getElementById("mainInput").select();
    });
  </script>
```